# Hyperledger Fabric - Node JS Shim - getHistoryForKey()

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

For Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 (leveldb as statedb) there is a specific API that returns a transaction history for a given key:

```
ctx.stub.getHistoryForKey(orderKey)
```

I am testing 2 scenarios:

1. querying a transaction history for one key - point query
2. querying a transaction history for a range of keys (several call to getHistoryForKey in the loop) - range query

For the data I have 2 cases:

1. One million entries in key:value format sorted by key inserted the ledger.
2. The same one million entries in key:value format in random order inserted to the ledger.

Sorted data:

1. Point Query (avg of 10 measures): 643 ms
2. Range Query (avg of 10 measures): 6s 645 ms

Unsorted data:

1. Point Query (avg ...): 661 ms
2. Range Query (avg ...): 24 s 351 ms

Questions that I have:

1. Is there a better way to do range queries?
2. My intuition is that Point Queries should be costlier for unsorted data compared to sorted one, because we need to access more blocks compared to sorted data case. But the results I get tells that it takes the same time to complete point query for both sorted and unsorted data. Why?
3. If getHistoryForKey() does not depend on the order of data inserted, why do the range query results differ?